# SQL Server connection on smart device

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-ce, smart-device

I wanted to know if it’s possible to use a SQL Server database connection  on a smart device? On the internet I found some solutions to use it but I also found people saying that you need to use SQL Server CE connection.

Source: ["Can't find PInvoke DLL 'dbnetlib.dll'." error in Smart Device Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838161/cant-find-pinvoke-dll-dbnetlib-dll-error-in-smart-device-application)

Here it looks like someone is using a normal database connection and got it fixed

But here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?681717-dbnetlib-dll-error

Someone is saying that you can only use SQL Server CE database connection.
So my question is can you use a SQL Server connection on a smart device or do you need to use SQL Server CE connection?

Comment: What have you tried - just copy/apply the correct CAB file to the device and add a reference to System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: Yes that’s what I did but when I install the CAB file on my mobile device I get an error (An Unexpected error has occurred) when I am starting my project. So I can’t start my project without the error. But when I delete all the code for the database connection I can start the project. Also if I install sql.wce5.armv4i CAB file then my project can start but I get the error when I make the connection to the database.

Comment: The WM SqlClient only supports certain connection string options - so PLEASE share the error message from your second scenario and the error message - otherwise how cna we help you