# How to connect windows CE c# application to database SQL Server2008r2

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-ce

Please help.
I have device MC3200 Zebra(motorola)(Windows Embedded version 7, build 2864). This device is connecting to network and see SQL server(ping is OK). I used it Visual Studio 2008, c#, SmartDevicePrj, .NET CF 3.5

[image]

But after start application on device will be displayed message:

> Unknown connection option in connection string: initial catalog.

Some idea how to repair it?

Many thanks for your help.

```
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

namespace SmartDeviceProject1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public SqlCeConnection msConn;
        public string strCon = "";
        public SqlCeCommand command;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            strCon = "Data Source=server007; Initial Catalog=FMPredlis; User ID=mistr; Password=heslo;";
            try
            {
                msConn = new SqlCeConnection(strCon);
                msConn.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Připojeno");
            }
            catch (SqlCeException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Chyba" + ex.Message);
                msConn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the windows CE device can look up the name "server007" as a name?

Comment: IIRC, SqlCeConnections are specified like "Data Source=MyData.sdf" and cannot be connected to a "real" SQL server at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing 2 things.

Either use The SqlConnection object, then you can connect to a SQL Server using a connection string found on this page:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Or use like in your code the SqlCEConnection, then you connect to a SQL Lite (local file), and your connection string should be like on this page:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/

But in your sample you are using SqlCEConnection to connect to a sql server, that wont work.

Grtz

Comment: Yes I actually mixed two things. At the start of the project I had a problem with the System.Data.SqlClient reference, so I went out of the way.
Now everything is working. I still had a problem with dbnetlib.dll, but I have solved it by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838161/cant-find-pinvoke-dll-dbnetlib-dll-error-in-smart-device-application
Many thanks for your help!