# .NET CF 2013 with SQL questions

Tags: .net, sql-server, ms-access, dll, compact-framework

Here I got a platform based on .NET CF 2013. And I want to manipulate Microsoft Office Access database through it. It seems that I need a `System.Data.SqlClient.dll` and maybe a `dbnetlib.dll`, also. The problem is I cannot find a `dbnetlib.dll` that can be quoted into the project.

Each time I tried to quote it, I get this error:

> Cannot copy the referenced assembly, failed to load the file or assembly 'dbnetlib.dll' or one of it's dependency. The module should contain a list of assemblies.

I think this should be the problem of list of assemblies, which I'm not familiar with. Is there anyone who had been working with this problems? How could I solve this?

I'm sorry that the error message is after translation from Chinese.

Comment: Why have you tagged SQL Server if the question is about MS Access?

Comment: Sorry， it should be OleDb, am I right?

Comment: I don't know - but I don't think SQL Server is involved.

Comment: Thank you，Sir. 
I'm focusing on creating, accessing database(including read and writing), so if I can manipulate SQL on this paltform, I would choose it.

Comment: Well, `System.Data.SqlClient` is SQL Server, not Access. However, this question is not reproducible as currently presented. Please add details/code

Comment: @Erik A: Thank you for your comment, Sir. My code is not added, because I just try to quote using System.Data.SqlClient.dll and add dll from software quoted assemblies menu, and error occurs. The project is a HMI of brand Beijer, and the software for developping is iX Developer SP4 provided by Beijer.

Comment: @sxjice Well, I suggest you contact the vendor then, because you probably need that project to reproduce that issue and no-one here has it

Comment: The metioned project HMI and develop fir IX Developer SP4 is unknown to me. But did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838161/cant-find-pinvoke-dll-dbnetlib-dll-error-in-smart-device-application. The right dbnetlib.dll or CAB file depends on the processor of the target device and OS.

Comment: @josef ：Yes, Sir. The dbnetlib.dll is just the location the comment mentioned. But I did encountered this problem. The vender told me that that dll should have lots of assemblies which they did not know either.